# running a python script which takes a directory name (given by the user) as argument

Tags: python

I am building a face recognition model on python. I have created a directory by a name taken from user input. Now I want to run a python file which takes pictures using camera and stores its output in that directory which was created. This python file takes the path of the output (where it has to store pictures from camera) as its arguments. Therefore tell me how can I use the name of directory created  as arguments of this python file ?

In this code I have created a variable "name" which would take input from user and create a directory by that name in the next line of the above code "os.makedirs(name)". Now in the next command i.e "os.system" I am trying to run a python file which should take the "--output argument" as the path to the directory created by the name from a user. I am able to run this python script but it doesnot take the "name" of directory as argument. Please help me how can I do it ? I am able to run this python script but it doesnot take the "name" of directory as argument.

```
import os
import sys

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Face registration")
print("2.Face Recognition")

# Take input from the user 

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2):")
name = input("Enter your name:")

if choice == '1':
    os.makedirs(name)
    os.system("python /home/pi/pi-face-recognition/dataset.py --cascade /home/pi/pi-face recognition/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml --output /home/pi/pi-face-recognition/dataset/name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass name as an argument in your system command. At the moment you're just passing the string `"name"`. Here I've used f-strings but you could use `.format()` or string concatenation if you like. I've split the line too to make it more readable.

```py
...
    os.system(f'python /home/pi/pi-face-recognition/dataset.py '
          f'--cascade /home/pi/pi-face recognition/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml '
          f'--output /home/pi/pi-face-recognition/dataset/{name}')
```